# How to properly use order_by with nulls_last on a related one_to_many field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to filter and order objects by existance of a related model with forcing nulls as last.

Example models:

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...


class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, related_name=model_b)
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    ...
```

Now, I need to filter ModelA by some kwargs (normal operations), but I also need to order ModelA by **nearest ModelB date and time** (in future, not past) **ascending or descending WITH A SINGLE QUERY PARAM** and also **NULLS need to be placed last** regardless of ascending or descending order.

I already came to a conclusion that I need to overwrite default QuerySet order_by:

```py
class ModelAQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def order_by(self, *field_names):
        if 'model_a_date' in field_names or '-model_a_date' in field_names:
            field_names = list(field_names)
            if 'model_a_date' in field_names:
                field_names.remove('model_a_date')
                return super().order_by(
                    'model_b__date',
                    'model_b_time',
                    *field_names
                )
            else:
                field_names.remove('-model_a_date')
                return super().order_by(
                    '-model_b__date',
                    '-model_b__time',
                    *field_names
                )
        else:
            return super().order_by(*field_names)
```

It works fine when I'm ordering descending (`'-model_a_date'`), since NULLS are last, but I'm having a hard time placing nulls last in ascending order. I already tried:

```py
return super().order_by(
    F('model_b').asc(nulls_last=True),
    'model_b__date',
    'model_b__time',
    *field_names
)

####

return super().order_by(
    F('model_b').asc(nulls_last=True)
).order_by(
    'model_b__date',
    'model_b_time',
    *field_names
)

####

return super().order_by(
    'model_b__date',
    'model_b_time',
    *field_names
).order_by(
    F('model_b').asc(nulls_last=True),
)
```

but that does not work at all. Either when I put inside order_by along with other arguments, or as a separate order_by in front or after the above order_by.

Any ideas on that? Has anyone bumped into such problem? I'm in a pickle here and honestly I ran out of ideas. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I also tried .union like so:

```py
ModelA.objects.annotate(
    modelbs=Count('modelb')
).filter(
    modelbs__gt=0
).union(
    ModelA.objects.annotate(
        modelbs=Count('model_b')
    ).filter(
        modelbs=0
    )
)
```

But this comes out with an error:

`ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use chain you can :

- first filter the elements that are not null order them by ascending or descending order
- second select the nulls
- finally you will be able to chain the to qs that you have (with nulls at the end) and return it

Does that make sense ?

Comment: This does sound like an idea. It's just most of the job is done in DRF automatically, so ordering happens after all filtering. I guess I'll need to overwrite some more functions.